# Connect to mqtt.googleapis.com:8883 via proxy and another domain

Tags: nginx, ssl, google-cloud-platform, paho

For some reasons our infra blocks `mqtt.googleapis.com`. That's why was deployed nginx proxy with such configuration

```
stream {
    upstream google_mqtt {
            server mgtt.googleapis.com:8883;
    }
    server {
            listen 8883;
            proxy_pass google_mqtt;
    }
}
```

Also it has external IP with domain name `fake.mqtt.com`

Using example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/iot/api-client/mqtt_example) I'm testing connectivity.
If script to run against `mgtt.googleapis.com:8883` everything works fine.
But if domain switch to `fake.mqtt.com` got an error:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'fake.mqtt.com'
```

For client implementation was used `paho.mqtt.client`.

Auth to mqtt broker realized with JWT.

```
def create_jwt(project_id, private_key_file, algorithm):
    token = {
        # The time that the token was issued at
        "iat": datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        # The time the token expires.
        "exp": datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=20),
        # The audience field should always be set to the GCP project id.
        "aud": project_id,
    }

    # Read the private key file.
    with open(private_key_file, "r") as f:
        private_key = f.read()

    print(
        "Creating JWT using {} from private key file {}".format(
            algorithm, private_key_file
        )
    )
    return jwt.encode(token, private_key, algorithm=algorithm)
```

Set JWT

```
client.username_pw_set(
            username='unused',
            password=create_jwt(project_id, private_key_file, algorithm))
```

TLS configuration:

```
client.tls_set(ca_certs='roots.pem', tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,)
```

Could you advise what to configure on nginx/paho-client side and is it working solution at all?

Or may be 3party brokers can connect to `mqtt.googleapis.com`? (from information i read here and on another resources - no)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not just arbitrarily change the domain name if you are just stream proxying, it needs to match the one presented in the certificate by the remote broker or as you have seen it will not validate.

You can force the client to not validate the server name by setting `client.tls_insecure_set(True)` but this is a VERY bad idea and should only be used for testing and never in production.

Comment: thank you for answer.
Could you advise what i can change if not "just stream proxying"?

Comment: Use something like a Socks proxy or set up the internal DNS server to direct `mqtt.googleapis.com` to your proxy machine so the DNS name matches.

Comment: Sock proxy  works, but i try to find solution which will not require code change. 
in my case it will not work (mean internal DNS), but thanks for giving direction!